# Ant copy task slower on 11.04 than 10.04

Tags: ant, build-automation, ubuntu-11.04

We use ant as part of our build system for copying a load of various files around, on 10.04 the entire process takes ~5 minutes, however as we've now started to shift onto 11.04 as our primary development platform we've noticed that it now takes ~25 minutes which is a fairly large factor to increase.

Has anyone noticed anything similar or have we just got some strange issue?

EDIT: https://gist.github.com/2049693 a gist of a 2 minute overview of vmstat running whilst a very heavy ant copy task runs.

EDIT: More info, both 10.04 and 11.04 run Java 1.6, Ant version on 10.04 is 1.7.1, Ant version on 11.04 is 1.8.0 (both installed from Ubuntu main repo's). Executing one of our biggest copy processes is actually *visibly* slower when run with verbose on.

EDIT: Issue occurs with the latest version of ant (1.8.3) installed both from binary and from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice anything when we upgraded. Our build still takes 10 minutes.

Here is a list of factors which can contribute to this:

1. You run more processes which need more RAM, so the OS doesn't have enough free buffers to cache files.
2. Are you still on the same type of filesystem? The update might have migrated to ext4.
3. Did you try to run the build on an old box to make sure it's not some change in the build itself.
4. What's the load on the machine?
5. Did you add XML files with DTDs/Schemas? Some XML parsers actually try to download these from the Internet.

**[EDIT]** This blog post lists tools to find out where the performance goes on Linux: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html

Comment: 1) Machines are still the same, and as far as I can see there's nothing taking up more memory but I'll double check that.

2) Same file system, both installs are ext4.

3) Same boxes exhibit the same behaviour.

4) Minimal load, I've tried it on various machines from a Core2Duo with 2Gb of RAM to a Dell PowerEdge Quad Core Xeon with 4Gb and a faster HDD and it's the same.

5) Nothing new added, exact same scripts.

Comment: Run the command with `time ant ...`. That gives you an idea where time is spent (kernel or user=process). See also my edits.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I ended up taking your advice. Real time clocks in 27m but user clocks in at 3m and sys at 0m 41s. So it's not hitting an issue with CPU execution time but something else entirely.

Comment: 24 minutes are spent in the kernel, in some kind of IO. See the link about monitoring tools to see where the time goes.

Comment: Yeah I'm running iostat now to see if I can spot where, I know it's most specifically in our ant tasks that use the cp command more so I'm guessing disk I/O.

Comment: Sounds like your build server has not enough RAM to cache the files. Check the value of `Buffers:` in the output of `cat /proc/meminfo` and compare that to `MemTotal:`

Comment: MemTotal:        2051120 kB 
MemFree:           80880 kB
Buffers:          256056 kB

Comment: Add 2-4GB of RAM to the machine (costs less than $100) and see how that helps.

Comment: I could do that but it'd be frivolous, I've run the test on a machine with double the amount of RAM and double the amount of processors and it's the exact (within a minute or two) time for execution. And the machine also doesn't have an issue building the *exact* same task on 10.04, so I don't think vertical scale will help on this one.

Comment: Okay. Then it's maybe a driver issue unless some of the sources are on a network/NFS drive...

Comment: Check `/var/log/*` for error messages. Maybe one of the hard disks is failing.

Comment: No errors in any syslogs, hard drive is fine (still builds in ~5 minutes on 10.04 on the same box), only possible driver issue is if something in 11.04 has affected SATA drivers (which would be noticeable) and nothing is on a NAS/network drive, all local.

Comment: Try `hdparm -t` and `-T` to measure the I/O performance of the disk

Comment: Disk I/O performance is fine. For example at the moment I have 11.04 with VirtualBox running 10.04 from a VMDK from RAW disk file (in this case the exact same drive). Ant build takes ~12 minutes within this VM (performance hit expected), compared to 28 minutes for the exact same task in 11.04 as the host OS. That rules out disk I/O really, and focuses it on ant in particular.

Comment: Both as full non-virtual installs on the same hardware, I've got the 10.04 one running in a VM so I don't have to reboot all the time.

Comment: err ... I mean the **Java VM** version ;-)

Comment: Too many VM's ;) I added the Java VM version in the original post, both on 1.6.

Comment: hm.... okay, I must admit that I have no idea what else could cause this. Maybe you can time how long the shell command `cp` would need to copy the data :-/

Comment: I'm going to say it's solved based off this http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ubuntu-11.04-natty-narwhal,2943-14.html being fairly damning of 11.04's file copy vs 10.04. But, as the bounty said if you get me close enough to puzzle it out enjoy your bonus points!

Comment: The review says that 11.04 is about 30% slower than 10.04 which doesn't account for your 400% slowdown. :-/

Comment: True, but I'm guessing that it's not limited to copy, we have a lot of other file tree based operations going on and we're incurring a performance penalty on all.

Comment: But why is the performance OK when copy files in a VM running on 11.04? That rules out the SATA/disk drivers. Maybe someone encrypted the file systems during/after the upgrade to 11.04?

Comment: Because the VM is writing directly to the disk and not to a virtual hard disk in this case (using VirtualBox's raw disk functionality). So effectively 10.04 is running directly to the disk with it's own copy operations rather than writing to a virtual drive, although I'd bet that writing via a normal virtual disk would be fine.

Comment: A raw disk image in a VM still uses the host OS's disk driver. Which leaves two culprits: The `cp` command and the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem with version 1.8.0 on Ubuntu 11.04. Upgraded to 1.9.2 and now the copy is much faster.

I followed the instruction from this [site](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/apache-ant.html) as apt-get was installing version 1.8.